# calling setting screen from activity or fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am developing an android application in which I have to call wireless settings activity of android from my activity. I am using this code

```
Intent i = new Intent();
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                                        "com.android.settings.WirelessSettings");
i.setComponent(cn);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

This code works fine upto android 2.3.7.But when I run it on android 4.0.1 (ICS)
 it gives me following error.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.WirelessSettings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I check into source code of android and found that , In android 2.3.7 WirelessSettings is an activity and in android 4.0.1 wireless settings changed to fragment . Have a look at these 2 pictures.
[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code for opening Wireless setting screen

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But it is giving error "ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Comment: I paste it into eclipse , it didn't identify "ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS" in android 2.2.

Comment: you need correct import use **import android.provider.Settings;**